# Drag scroll with inertia

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to create an effect like the iphone touch screen drag scroll with inertia but for a desktop browser.

It seems like this is the code that I'm after:

```
smoothstep_eo(t) = 2*smoothstep((t+1)/2) - 1
```

From here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/196209/348174

But I'm having difficulty working out how to implement it.

I imagine using that code somehow to calculate the movement of a click, drag and release and then applying the value to scrollToTop() frame by frame.

Any advice on how to approach this.

Comment: The mac OS already has that style of scrolling. Are you trying to implement it for windows?

Comment: Read the post you linked fully not only the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Cubiq.org's iScroll 5](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll).

It's a jQuery plugin that works really well and does all the emulating of touch-by-mouse perfectly fine.